# The type 'short' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TTargetEntity' in the generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I try to add a configuration using Fluent API As following :

```
public class PeriodTypeMappings: EntityTypeConfiguration<PeriodType>
    {
        public PeriodTypeMappings()
        {
            this.HasKey(p => p.PeriodTypeId);
            this.Property(p => p.PeriodTypeName).HasMaxLength(value: 25);
            this.HasRequired(p => p.PeriodTypeName);
            this.HasRequired(p => p.NumberOfPartitions);//compile error
        }
    }
```

---

But i get the following exception :

> The type 'short' must be a reference type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'TTargetEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'EntityTypeConfiguration.HasRequired(Expression>)'

The exception occured at last line `this.HasRequired(p => p.NumberOfPartitions);` where `NumberOfPartitions` is of type short .

Why this happened and how to fix this problem , i try to say that this field is required .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*HasRequired* is used for mapping *navigation properties*. What you are looking for is *IsRequired*. But if your property is not nullable, it is required by default. Your mapping should look like this:

```
this.HasKey(p => p.PeriodTypeId);

this.Property(p => p.PeriodTypeName)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(25);

this.Property(p => p.NumberOfPartitions)
    .IsRequired();
```